# Remove textareafield border

Tags: javascript, extjs

How do i border of the textareafield, surrounding the text.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
    title      : 'Sample TextArea',
    width      : 400,
border     : false,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo   : Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype     : 'textareafield',
        grow      : true,
        name      : 'message',
        fieldLabel: 'Message',
        anchor    : '100%'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the box around the text the user enters?  Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, for example, you are working with ExtJs 5.1, and also that you wish to remove the border from the input field (More info would help narrow down variables), you could define a cls for your component and then define the border for the inputfield as "none",

```
{
    xtype     : 'textareafield',
    grow      : true,
    name      : 'message',
    fieldLabel: 'Message',
    cls       : 'xpto',
    anchor    : '100%',
}
```

and your css would be

```
.xpto .x-form-trigger-wrap-default {border: none;}
```

Checking the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text) is always helpful and can provide with examples and insight though.

Comment: Or just set the sass variable `$form-field-border-width` http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-css_var-S-form-field-border-width

Answer (score 0):

To display data on a form and be able to use `form.loadRecord()` and other benefits of the form panel you can use [`displayfield`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display)

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 175,
    height: 150,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Final Score',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Home',
        name: 'home_score',
        value: '10'
    }, {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Visitor',
        name: 'visitor_score',
        value: '11'
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Update'
    }]
});
```